# React JSON API gives this.state.map not a function error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, mapping

Hey I have been trying to figure out a fix for this for a while, I've searched here and all over but I've found nothing.

I have an API, it contains nested arrays, and is given through JSON.

I am able to get the contents inside the JSON to display when I use the console.log, but when I try to map the arrays, I constantly get errors stating that there's an issue with the .map function.

From what I have seen, it usually happens because it doesn't work with a string, but it's not being applied to a string from what I can tell...

There's a lot of data in the API, but I'm sure once I know how to get just one, eg the date, to display then I'll be fine with the rest.

Here is the code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {     
        myItem: [] 

    };

}

componentDidMount() {

    this.getItems();
}

getItems () {
    fetch('MYAPIGOESHERE')


        .then(results => results.json())

        //THIS BELOW WORKS
        .then(results => console.log(results.date, results.location));

        //THIS BELOW AND THE RENDER DOES NOT
        .then(myItem => this.setState({myItem}))

}


render() {        
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.myItem.map (myItem => 
                    <div> {myItem.date} </div> )}
        </div>
    )
})
}
}
```

Thank you!

```
{"date":"2018-09-16T11:22:00.000Z","location":"Cardiff City Stadium","teams":[{"name":"Cardiff City","homeTeam":true,"formation":"4-4-2","players":[{"playerId":"5afc0b73b481e9b536c4727b","position":"GK"},{"playerId":"5afc1377b481e9b536c4727c","position":"RB"},{"playerId":"5afc188bb481e9b536c47299","position":"CB"},{"playerId":"5afc188ab481e9b536c47297","position":"CB"},{"playerId":"5afc1872b481e9b536c4727e","position":"LB"},{"playerId":"5afc1873b481e9b536c4727f","position":"RM"},{"playerId":"5afc1874b481e9b536c47280","position":"CM"},{"playerId":"5afc1876b481e9b536c47281","position":"CM"},{"playerId":"5afc1876b481e9b536c47282","position":"LM"},{"playerId":"5afc1876b481e9b536c47283","position":"FW"},{"playerId":"5afc1877b481e9b536c47284","position":"FW"}]},{"name":"Swansea City","homeTeam":false,"formation":"4-3-3","players":[{"playerId":"5afc187ab481e9b536c4728a","position":"GK"},{"playerId":"5afc1878b481e9b536c47286","position":"RB"},{"playerId":"5afc1879b481e9b536c47289","position":"CB"},{"playerId":"5afc187ab481e9b536c4728b","position":"CB"},{"playerId":"5afc187bb481e9b536c4728c","position":"LB"},{"playerId":"5afc1879b481e9b536c47288","position":"RM"},{"playerId":"5afc1878b481e9b536c47287","position":"CM"},{"playerId":"5afc187bb481e9b536c4728d","position":"LM"},{"playerId":"5afc187cb481e9b536c47290","position":"FW"},{"playerId":"5afc187db481e9b536c47291","position":"FW"},{"playerId":"5afc187db481e9b536c47292","position":"FW"}]}]}
```

Comment: Can you show the shape of the data returned from the API please?

Comment: Also as it is, your second `.then()` isn't returning anything to use in the third `.then()`.

Comment: have you tried: `.then(match => this.setState({myItem: match}));`???

Comment: @Colin Hey! Yep, I know the `.then()` section is odd in the above, I was just displaying the two that I've been testing with. I code out one or the other when I run it. And what do you mean the shape of the data??

Comment: Like, what does the API response look like?

Comment: @Colin If I pull the full API response then it looks like a squashed up JSON response with no structure. Is this what you mean?? Or are you referring to the amount of arrays in the API response???

Comment: I mean that right now I have no idea what the structure of the data looks like, so I can't help.

Comment: @Colin Ahh my bad, I thought I included! I just pasted the whole JSON response in the question. Thank you, by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map over `this.state.myItem` because it's an object.

You could do:

```
<div>{this.state.myItem.date}</div>
```

If you have an array of objects, you can do:

```
<div>{this.state.myItems.map(e => <div>{e.date}</div>)}</div>
```

for example.

If you have an object with an array in it, you can do:

```
const { teams } = this.state.myItem;
<div>{teams.map(t => <div>{t}</div>)}</div>
```

The data you have is like this: Object --> Array --> Object, so you can combine the above to display the data you want.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!! But one final question, how do I perform the same but for an array of data for the object?

Comment: You mean an array of objects?

Comment: Yup, and I did what you have added above, and I replaced `date` with `teams` which holds only two pieces of data, but I keep getting the map.error again

Comment: Ah, you don't mean an array of objects then, you mean an object with an array in it.

Comment: Ooohhh okay, thank you! I'm assuming that I can just place the code snippet above for the array data into the return statement, along with the singular objects, and then I will have both date object and teams array be rendered at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping setState in braces:

```
    .then(myItem => {
       this.setState({myItem})
    })
```

Map function works with arrays, you seem to have a single object. Try this:

```
    return (
       <div> {this.state.myItem.date} </div>
    )
```

and remove the space between map and the opening parentheses.